# Can 'bad' user modify ajax post request?

Tags: ajax

Here is an abstract example:
2 types of users (`user` and `admin`) have some data, that they can change on their's *Profile Page*.

`user` can change only his own data, but `admin` can change data of any `user`.

On the *Profile page* of admin there is such a code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {
        'action' : 'data_change',
        'user_id': $("#user_id").val()
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

But on *Profile page* of user there is such a code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {
        'action' : 'my_data_change'
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

Here, for example `my_data_change` action (php function) gets user id from session.

Is it safe? For example some 'bad user' used to be an admin, but now is a user. So he may know how to send request (may be likes to watch in firebug). 
It turns out, that with easy request modification any user can modify another user's data.

But is it really to modify request locally from browser? In this example, is it really to change `my_data_change` action to `data_change` and add `user_id` parameter to request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can modify all the requests they want, they still need to physically log into the server, or your `some.php` file can simply deny the request as unauthenticated (use sessions!). Once authenticated, the server knows whether the user is an admin or not, and can further check that the client has the proper permissions for the operation requested.

The system is about as safe as you make it (give or take an unintended bug or two).

Answer (score 2):

If some.php is checking the identity of the user in a secure way (e.g. via something already established in a session), and confirming that the user is indeed an admin before doing *anything at all* with the 'user_id' parameter - yes, it should be safe.